# Eclipse crear nueva combinacion teclas

Tags: java, eclipse

Me gustaría crear una palabra clave como <kbd>sysout</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Barra espaciadora</kbd>, para que se automatizase el `System.out.println`. El caso sería para escribir `public static final`, o bien con una combinación tipo <kbd>psf</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Espacio</kbd> o directamente que con una combinación de teclas lo hiciese. Sería para *Eclipse Neon*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea un nuevo *Template* (plantilla)<sup>1</sup>.

El asistente de contenido utiliza plantillas para permitir el uso de fragmentos de código comunes. Para crear una nueva plantilla:

1. Click en **Window** > **Preferences**.
2. Expande **Java**, expande **Editor** y selecciona **Templates**.
3. Click en **New**.

[image: pantalla]

---

*Notas*

1. Véase [*Creating and editing templates*](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_add_codetemp.htm).

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto funciona genial! thanks

Comment: Sí. Yo sé. No fue nada.

Answer (score 0):

La ruta para cambiar la configuracion es:

> window -> preferences -> java -> editor -> content assist

Comment: Ahí sólo sale la opción de activar, pero no veo cómo añadir esa combinación....